# Creating an array from posted variables php

Tags: php, arrays

advanced apologies for what seems like a simple question that I thought would have been answered 1000's of times, but I can't find an answer to this simple question.

I have a form that has radioboxes and checkboxes.  I dynamically echo out 20 rows of articles from a mysqli database, with the radio and checkboxes echoing the article_id as a value under each article, allowing me to choose one article as a lead article and up to 20 other news articles.  I can post the radio box no problem and save it as a variable. I can create a manual PHP array!  But how can I create an array from the posted checkboxes with all the checked article id values.

```
<div class="email-set-up-radio-buttons">
    <span class="slider-text">Lead news story</span><br/>
 <label class="switch">
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="leadNewsStory" value="<?php echo $row ['article_id'] ?>">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
</div>
    <br/>
<div class="email-set-up-checkbox-buttons">
    <span class="slider-text">Add to newsletter</span><br/>
 <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="addToNewsletter[]" value="<?php echo $row ['article_id'] ?>">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
</div>
                                    
</div>
```

This is then passed to my php script

```
<?php 
    
// simple post that I am able to echo out and save in a variable
$leadNewsStory = $_POST['leadNewsStory'];
echo $leadNewsStory.'<br/>';

// NOT WORKING I need to create array of checkboxed named addToNewsletter to gather in an array
$addToNewsletter = array($_POST["addToNewsletter"]);
    print_r($addToNewsletter).'<br/>';
    
    
//this works as I have created the array manually 
    $add = array("224071", "224070", "224069");
    print_r($add)

    
?>
```

I need to create an array from all the checked checkboxes that are passed to my php script

Comment: `addToNewsletter[]` will already come in as an array of all checkboxes that were checked. If a checkbox is NOT checked, it will not be in the array of `$_POST["addToNewsletter"]`. This is wrong: `$addToNewsletter = array($_POST["addToNewsletter"]);` ... you just need `$addToNewsletter = $_POST["addToNewsletter"];` (well you dont need that, but if it makes your code more readable, then re-assign it like that).

Comment: @IncredibleHat Thank you!

$addToNewsletter = $_POST["addToNewsletter"]; Works perfectly

No wonder I couldn't find an answer to what know feels like a silly question, but I really appreciate you answering this. Thanks again

Comment: When in doubt with forms, `var_dump($_POST)` and see what you're receiving.